# Prompted for key password when key is in ssh-agent

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

In an old shell session, the number of ssh keys in `ssh-agent` tends to be large enough to fail authentication with the server, simply because the client just throws keys at it, FIFO fashion. It seems to do this even if the `IdentityFile` directive is specified for the relevant host in `~/.ssh/config`.

To remedy that, I added the `IdentitiesOnly` directive to said file. Now, however, I'm prompted for an ssh key password when I attempt to connect to the server. This, despite the fact that the key is in `ssh-agent`. When I remove `IdentitiesOnly` from the configuration file, no prompt is presented and access is granted.

So, my questions is, how can I ensure that the correct key (and no other) is presented to a given server *and* avoid being prompted for that key's password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across the solution in [this blog post](https://blog.mithis.net/archives/useful-bits/2172-using-identitiesonly-without-key-files).

Essentially, the idea is to refer to the public key, not the private key, in the `IdentityFile` declaration. So the final configuration for host `foo` would be something like this:

```
Host foo
    Hostname foo.org
    User admin
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/foo.pub
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```